# How do I identify this trap error in WinBUGS?

Tags: bayesian, survival, bugs

I am currently working on my thesis and interested in estimating a Weibull conditional Hazard Frailty Model for recurrent event data using WinBUGS. I wrote the model but when am trying to use it with the following script it hangs unexpectedly. It returns a messages titled "undefined real result". What am I doing wrong? Also, I have tried different prior and initial values but I could not solve the problem!

```
model
{
for(i in 1:633){
ht[i]<-gama*pow((t[i]),(gama-1))*exp(age[i]*b[1]+sex[i]*b[2]+mar[i]*b[3]+back1[i]*b[4]+back2[i]*b[5]+form[i]*b[6]+u[subject[i]]+delta*enu[i])
}
for(i in 1:633){
beta[i]<-pow((1/gama),((gama*pow((t[i]),(gama-1)))/ht[i]))
}
for(i in 1:633){
t[i]~dweib(gama,beta[i]) I(cen[i],)
}
for (j in 1:6){
b[j]~dnorm(0,0.001)
}
for(i in 1:159){
u[i]~dnorm(0,tau)
}
delta~dnorm(0,0.01)
gama~dgamma(1,0.01)
tau~dunif(0,100)
sigma2.subject<-1/tau
}
list(b=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),gama=1,tau=1,delta=0)
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me for solving this problem.

Comment: From my experience, this message is displayed when there is a very big (infinity for BUGS) number obtained, e.g. 10e100 or something. In addition, the diffuse gamma prior distribution usually is the cause of this. I would recommend to use uniforma distribution instead of gamma. Also, from my experience, gamma prior is is quite informative, i.e. influences posterior more that uniform.

Comment: Although this sounds like a software-specific error, as the comment by @Tomas demonstrates, tracking it down will likely require significant statistical experience and reasoning.  I vote to keep this one open here on CV.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to numerical overflow, which is also stated in [this](http://mathstat.helsinki.fi/openbugs/Manuals/TipsTroubleshooting.html) troubleshooting guide for Bugs.

> '**undefined real result**' indicates numerical overflow. Possible reasons include:
>    - initial values generated from a 'vague' prior distribution may be numerically extreme - specify appropriate initial values;
>    - numerically impossible values such as log of a non-positive number - check, for example, that no zero expectations have been given when Poisson modelling;
>    - numerical difficulties in sampling. Possible solutions include:
>    - better initial values;
>    - more informative priors - uniform priors might still be used but with their range restricted to plausible values;
>    - better parameterisation to improve orthogonality;
>    - standardisation of covariates to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1.
>    - can happen if all initial values are equal.

So there are a number of different things to consider, and we cannot evaluate problems in your data. Since you have tried different initial values this can maybe be ruled out. I would suggest that you look closely at your data and maybe try to standardise variables.

Have you checked the data for problems? For instance, you are using `beta[i]` as a parameter in the Weibull distribution, and from what I know this must be >0. If any value in `beta[i]` is zero this might cause this error.

In your model, one if the definitions is `t[i]~dweib(gama,beta[i]) I(cen[i],)`, which looks a bit strange and is probably a typo. What is `I(cen[i],)` defining? It shouldn't be the reason for this particular error though.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: I(cen[i],) is WinBUGs' peculiar notation for left-truncation